# How do you make a Discord bot send an emoji when you give it the name of the emoji?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, replit

I'm trying to make my Discord bot send an emoji when I tell it the name. E.g., say I send !emoji hello, I want the bot to send back the emoji called hello.

If I send an emoji the bot will send it back but I'm not sure how to grab an emoji from its name being sent to the bot.

I use discord.js v12 for reference.

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried, we can help improve your code. This one is a rather simple answer but I’d rather steer you from where you are to the right answer rather than just give it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
bot.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    const exampleEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === message.content);
    channel.message.send(`Is this the emoji you want? ${exampleEmoji}`);
});
```

You can then nest it inside of your **if** statement as you please with whatever command you are using. This also should be v12/v13 compatible and I believe the only differences with older versions is whether you add cache or not to the find function.

You can also use the same function to find the emoji as a boolean to determine if the emoji exists or not and if not send a different message for feedback.

I also found this really interesting function which helped me when deciphering which emojis I have and which are not in the scope I am presenting.

```
if (message.content === "listemojis") {
   const emojiList = message.guild.emojis.cache.map((e, x) => `${x} = ${e} | ${e.name}`).join("\n");
   message.channel.send(emojiList);
}
```

Which will output this for every emoji within the scope you searched.

```
450661466287112204 = :image: | name
```

Which I found [here](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/using-emojis.md).
Hope this helps